# gui text box disappear when click on gui button in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my game I am displaying a textbox; I want it to disappear when i click the button. The code I have tried until now is:

```
private var isclick: boolean=true;

function OnGUI() {
    if (isclick==true){ 
        GUI.Label(new Rect(Screen.width/7,Screen.height/7,Screen.width,Screen.height),word); 
        words=word;

    if (GUI.Button(Rect(Screen.width/5,(Screen.height/4)+320,Screen.width/2,Screen.height/12),"remove")){ 
        isclick=false;    
    } 
}
```

`word` is text which is displaying on screen. When I click the button the text has to disappear, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you're having problem with indent and close bracers..

```
private var IsClicked : boolean = false;

function OnGUI() {
    if(!IsCliked) DrawWordGUI();
}

function DrawWordGUI() {
    words = GUI.Label(labelRect, words);
    if(GUI.Button(buttonRect, "Remove")) {
        IsClicked = true;
    }
}
```